# Java binary search tree delete

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm writing a delete method for a binary search tree, it isn't complete but I filled a tree so that I could at least test the case where the node I want to delete is a leaf but it doesn't seem to be working. Any obvious errors in my logic?

```
public void delete(E d)
{
    delete( d, root);
}

private void delete( E d, Node<E> T)
{
    if(T == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(d.equals(T.getData()))
    {
        System.out.println("it found the node at least");
        if(T.getRight() == null && T.getLeft() == null)
        {
            T.setData(null);
        }
        //do alot)
    }
    else if(d.compareTo(T.getData()) > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("going right");
        delete(d, T.getRight());
    }
    //s is less than T, insert on left subtree
    else
    {System.out.println("going left");
        delete(d,T.getLeft());
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is `//do alot)`?

Comment: Also, setting `data` to `null` isn't what I would call a deletion.

Comment: do alot means code the rest of the cases. and how would i delete it?

Comment: [BST deletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion).

Comment: Whats the problem? Are you unable to search the node?

Comment: To delete it, you'd actually need to set the parent's child pointer to `null` (which doesn't really fit too well into your current function, *hint: have the function return a `boolean` if deleted*).

Comment: the parent is the node that im deleting or the parent of the node that im deleting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not delete nodes. It just clears them.
In order to implement delete you must change your function *not* to be void but:

`private Node delete( E d, Node<E> T)`

And your code should be something like:

```
public void delete(E d) {
    root = delete( d, root);
}

private void delete( E d, Node<E> T)
{
    if(T == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(d.equals(T.getData()))
    {
        System.out.println("it found the node at least");
        if(T.getRight() == null && T.getLeft() == null)
        {
           return null;
        }
        //do alot)
    }
    else if(d.compareTo(T.getData()) > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("going right");
        T.right = delete(d, T.getRight());
    }
    //s is less than T, insert on left subtree
    else
    {
        System.out.println("going left");
        T.left = delete(d,T.getLeft());
    }

}
```

You get the idea...